# Duplicated informations

Tags: production, record

I’m looking for a way to know which are the “duplicated ” records in production .
I want to know witch are the leads record matching the following condition:
lead email=Contact email.

So check for each lead if there is (in all the org) a contact with the same mail.

Any idea?

I’m tring with report but looks impossible.

Thanks in advantage for any advice

Comment: Are you looking for just a one time dump of this data, or are you looking to set something up to prevent these duplicates?

Comment: i want to dump just one time,not preventing .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write an apex batch job that process all leads and looks for contacts with matching email.  If so flag affected records.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have written a little apex job and i have executed it from DEVELOPERCONSOLE-DEBUG-ANONYMOUS CODE.With this i setted a custom field checkbox (todelete__c)on lead , after i have created a report filtering on that checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DataLoader and extract Lead data and Contact data from the org and compare the email fields locally using Excel or Access or SQL Server, etc, to identify duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! it's possible but it's not the best solution, i solved with code.